# My ornamental pineapple plant

Tags: houseplants

The soil of my green pineapple plant has a lot of white & green round things,  what are they?  I don’t know what to do.[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you did not pot this plant yourself. The white things are perlite, usually used to enhance drainage. Although they don't break down in the soil, they should be rather crumbly; you could crush a large piece between your thumb and index finger.

The green balls appear to be a type of timed-release fertilizer (in the US, often sold under the name Osmocote). The color of the fertilizer is usually associated with a specific brand or fertilizer type. For example, regular Osmocote is tan colored, while the chelation version (used to add more iron to a plant) is a bright orange. In this case, the fertilizer could be made by a company called [Koch](https://kochturf.com/products/controlledrelease/polyon/).

Comment: I bought the plant potted like that.  The white things are just on top of soil.  Could it be possibly mold?  I see similar things on my corn plant before.  The green balls i see them under the soil too.

Answer (score 0):

The white things called perlite are not mold but help your plant with drainage. And the green balls are fertilizer which releases at a certain time. A little tip to growing ornamental pineapple plants is that you have to water them the same day every week.